# How to do Spring Cloud Steam Binder SPI resilience?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config

Initially configured following properties from application.properties:

spring.cloud.stream.defaultBinder: XXXXX
    spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.type : rabbit
    spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.environment.spring.rabbitmq.addresses : 
    spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.environment.spring.rabbitmq.username : ppp
    spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.environment.spring.rabbitmq.password : qqqq
    spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.environment.spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host : /com/llll/ccc

Later i would like to change spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.environment.spring.rabbitmq.addresses without stopping the server. I tried following way:

```
@Autowired
private EnvironmentManager poEnvironmentManager = null;

and the in the method 

poEnvironmentManager.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.binders.XXXXX.environment.spring.rabbitmq.addresses", ".......");
```

It was not working. Let me know if you have solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just change that property on the fly. It would mean that a new connection factory had to be created, probably a refresh of the application context. What were you trying to achieve here, switch the target broker at runtime?

Comment: Yes, switch the target broker at runtime. Similar thing we can achieve for DB connection factory by using @RefreshScope. It re-creates the factory. How I can achieve to refresh binder SPI without touching other bean refresh?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and I don't believe it's a good idea either. There would be a lot of coordination to happen in case a broker change mid flight. Messages that are still not processed, messages in retry, there's just too much that can go wrong with this. If you need to have your app point to another broker, just go with blue green deployments, start  a new one, point to the new broker, exhaust the old one and then terminate it.

Comment: We are creating a message bus infrastructure where message durable is not required. This bus will be used for specific purpose. Basically we are ok to move to another DR setup when it happened.

Comment: As of now it is not possible. So there are two ways we can achieve this: 1. Don't use Binder SPI, use your own customized code with @RefreshScope  2. Use Binder SPI, for resilience use /refresh ACTUATOR endpoint.

Comment: I'm sorry I think you are confusing what resilience really means and the fact that you want to swap a broker midflight. That has nothing to do with resilience. You should fix the title so others don't think this is whats happening here. As I said before, changing a broker mid flight is not a thing we support. If you need resilience configure rabbit for HA mode. If you embrace cloud native, use blue green deployments to change your configurations.